# Line of Business grammar

Tags: grammar, word-usage, ambiguity

What is the correct way to say "Line of Businesses" or "Line of Business"?

if you want to say multi or ten, twenty ie quantity. how do you add line of business?

is it "10 line of business", "10 lines of business" or "10 lines of businesses"?

"The partner company has 10 lines of business operating independently to serve customers. "

Here, the partner company has different departments such as financial, IT, HR etc. These are more or less departments within the company but they generate revenue as well. That is why they are called LoB.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more context please? Try to use it in a sentence with clues as to what the plural should imply.

Comment: I think the phrase 'line of business' uses 'business' in the sense of commercial activity in general, not 'a business' meaning an individual firm. So the plural is 'lines of business'.

Comment: Thanks @KateBunting . If you can write it as answer, I am happy to accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the phrase 'line of business' uses 'business' in the sense of commercial activity in general, not 'a business' meaning an individual firm. So the plural is 'lines of business'.

Comment: This is correct, just like you'd buy "two types of fruit", not "two type of fruits".